# Problems with PyMongo: Checking a collection

Tags: python, pymongo, discord, discord.py

I'm currently learning MongoDB using Python and I'm trying my projects with a discord bot. I would like to do some things but I don't know how to do them.

The first problem is the following:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, arg:str=None):
    db = client.db_test
    collection = db["test"]
    cursor = collection.find({"permission" : arg})
    if perm is not None:
        if perm == "x":
            for y in cursor:
                await bot.say(y)
```

The bot sends this message:

```
{'_id': '<id>', 'name': '<name>', 'permission': 'x'}
```

But I want it to send like:

```
<name> has permission x
```

The second question is the following:

I want to check if a user has permission "x" and print something like:

```
<name> has permission admin
```

How can I resolve and do that?

Comment: Why don't you create that string yourself since you have all the information you need?

Comment: Because I'm still learning and I don't know how I can do it for now.

Comment: I do not know how discord bot works (I found your post while doing reviewing stuff in SO). It is my guess that maybe you could replace `bot.say(y)` with `bot.say("{} has permission {}".format(y[name], y[permission]))` as `y` looks like a standard python `dict` object.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much @KyrSt !

Comment: did my suggestion work? If so, I should probably repost it as an answer

Comment: @KyrSt of course it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this segment:

```
            for y in cursor:
                await bot.say(y)
```

`y` is actually a Python `dict` as you can see when printing it out. In this case, all you have to do is take the values you want from the dictionary and create your string yourself.
That would be (using *str*'s *format()* method:

```
answer = "{} has permission {}".format(y["name"], y["permission"])
```

So, all you need to do is return that instead of y like tis:

```
            for y in cursor:
                answer = "{} has permission {}".format(y["name"], y["permission"])
                await bot.say(answer)
```